# Why should I declare a String as a fixed-size array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void copy_string(char string1[], char string2[]){
    int counter=0;
    while(string1[counter]!='\0'){
        string2[counter] = string1[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    string2[counter] = '\0';
}

int main() {
   char* myString = "Hello there!";
   char* myStringCopy;
   copy_string(myString, myStringCopy);
   printf("%s", myStringCopy);
}
```

My question is, why isn't it working unless I declare myStringCopy as a fixed-size variable (`char myStringCopy[12];`)? Shouldn't it work if I add a `\0` character after the copy as I'm doing?

Comment: The problem is that ther is no space allocated for `myStringCopy`. Its just an unitnitzialized pointer which points to no valid memery location, therefore you can not write to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char myStringCopy[12];` tells the compiler to create an array of 12 `char`. When `myStringCopy` is passed to `copy_string`, this array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so `copy_string` receives a pointer to the characters.

`char *myStringCopy;` tells the compiler to create a pointer to `char`. The compiler creates this pointer, including providing memory for it, but it does not set the value of the pointer. When this pointer is passed to `copy_string`, `copy_string` does not receive a valid value.

To make `char *myStringCopy;` work, you must allocate memory (which you can do with `malloc`). For example, you could use:

```
char *myStringCopy;
myStringCopy = malloc(13 * sizeof *myStringCopy);
if (myStringCopy == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, the malloc did not work.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also, note that 12 is not enough. The string “Hello there!” contains 12 characters, but it also includes a terminating null character. You must provide space for the null character. `char myStringCopy[12];` appeared to work, but `copy_string` was actually writing a thirteenth character beyond the array, damaging something else in your program.

Comment: And how could I do it without knowing the string length?

Comment: @CarlosMorente: You can find the string length by counting the characters in the source string, up to and including the terminating null character. Also, if you want `copy_string` to do the allocation, then it must return the newly allocated address to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

It can work by doing `char* myStringCopy` as long as you allocate memory space for it.

for example

```
char* myStringCopy
myStringCopy = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(myString)+1))
```

I might be mistaken about the +1 but I think it is like this.

Comment: [Dont cast malloc return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have room for `mystringCopy`

You need to reserve space first:

```
   char* myString = "Hello there!";
   char* myStringCopy = malloc(strlen(myString) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* myStringCopy;
```

This is only pointer to char*. You must first allocate memory for myStringCopy, before start copy. When you declare it like this:

```
char myStringCopy[12];
```

compiler allocate enough memory in stack.

Comment: i know, i only answer to question. and copy statement from user code.